# does anyone know this mysterious operator ">?" in GCC

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Does anyone know about `>?` operator? I have a macro with below definition which is throwing error, but I have never seen such an operator till now:

```
#define MAX_SIZEOF2(a,b)           (sizeof(a) >? sizeof(b))
```

Comment: This is surprisingly difficult to search for, I made a guess it was deprecated since it modern gcc does not recognize it.

Answer (score 6):

The *minimum and maximum operators* are a [deprecated gcc extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Deprecated-Features.html):

> The G++ minimum and maximum operators (‘`<?`’ and ‘`>?`’) and their compound forms (‘`>?=`’) and ‘`<?=`’) have been deprecated and are now removed from G++. Code using these operators should be modified to use `std::min` and `std::max` instead.

Here is what the [older documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.2/gcc/Min-and-Max.html) says:

> It is very convenient to have operators which return the “minimum” or
>   the “maximum” of two arguments. In GNU C++ (but not in GNU C),
>
> `a <? b`
>
> > is the minimum, returning the smaller of the numeric values a and b;
>
> `a >? b`
>
> > is the maximum, returning the larger of the numeric values a and b.

This had the advantage that it allowed you to avoid macros which could have issues with side-effects if they were not used carefully.

Answer (score 5):

I guess it has been removed from GCC version 4.2

The equivalent of `a >?= b` is `a = max(a,b);`

From the manual

> The G++ minimum and maximum operators (‘`<?`’ and ‘`>?`’) and their compound forms (‘`>?=`’) and ‘`<?=`’) have been deprecated and are now removed from G++. Code using these operators should be modified to use `std::min` and `std::max` instead.

**EDIT:**

From your comments, you need to add `#include <algorithm>` to use the `std::max` and `std::min`. You can also check this for [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max).

Comment: Is there any flag in GCC 4.8, so that i can enable >? . Because when i use std::max, i am getting error that max is not part of std or is there any alternate solution exist?

Comment: @vimalprathap:- Try to add `#include <algorithm>`. For reference you can check http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max

Answer (score 3):

It's a [deprecated non-standard operator](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Deprecated-Features.html#Deprecated-Features) which gives the maximum of its operands. GCC no longer supports it.

In C++, this is equivalent to `std::max(sizeof(a), sizeof(b))`.